# writing python code within a C# application

Tags: c#, python

I've been tasked with adding my python projects/scripts into existing C# applications as a part of a cross team development initiative and I know absolutely nothing about C# in general. I've found many articles on how add python to c++ applications, but my understanding is that the two c languages are different enough to where they require different approaches. I would really like to avoid having to use IronPython if possible, frankly because it sounds like I'll have to rewrite all of my python scripts in order to make it work. (If i understand IronPython correctly) I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. Is there a standard approach on how to incorporate existing python code into a C# application?

Comment: The standard approach is IronPython. Sounds like you're trying to do less work by doing more work to me, if you want to avoid IronPython.

Comment: The goal of IronPython is to allow .Net and Mono to run python code. There could be some differences, but ultimately it's probably going to be your best solution.

Comment: sorry, for the late response. I was expecting an email notification or something if I received a reply. I used IronPython at first and then completely rewrote the code in C#. Thanks for the input you two!